# JQuery Cycle NoConflict $ Issue

Tags: jquery, css

I had implemented the JQuery Cycle Plugin and it works without incident.

However when I try to link a seperate JavaScript that I would like to use for a Menu in the Head Section from here http://dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddmegamenu.htm

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ddmegamenu.js"></script>
```

either before or after the script tag for the Cycle:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.min.js"></script>
```

I get this Error: "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Here is my development site: http://www.virtualpetstore.com

The Debugger indicates that it's breaking here:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.slideshow').cycle({
            fx: 'fade'
        });
    });
```

Besides ditching the Dynamic Menu entirely, does anyone see a work-around for this?

Comment: What if you remove the duplicate reference to jQuery?

Comment: @uglymunky I just saw that- js/jquery.js  I commented it but made no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your "Dynamic Menu" script is calling jQuery's [`.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) method.

`.noConflict` relinquishes control of the `$` alias. In other words, when you're calling `.cycle()`, `$` no longer represents jQuery.

An easy workaround is to call the Cycle plugin like this:

```
jQuery('.slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'fade'
});
```

Comment: @Paul: Happy to help! Good luck with your project.

Comment: I have a follow-up question regarding this.  It appears the same thing is happening, however with another $.  Which strangely enough doesnt occur if I have 2 references to JQuery in the Head Section. I can append to my original question

Comment: @Paul: It's probably best to simply post a new question :)